# Eigenvalues of 2 ODES with a constant term?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following system and would like to convert to state space and/or matrix from to find the eigenvalues, however the constant terms are not in my analysis.

For example;
$$
 \ddot{x}_1 = -50x_1 + 5\dot{x}_2 - 250x_2 + 20 \\
\ddot{x}_2 = 5x_2 - x_1 +30
$$
So let $$A=\pmatrix{0& 1&0& 0\\
-50& 0& 1& -250\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
-1& 0& 5& 0} $$

So now

$$[A][x_1 , \dot{x_1}, x_2, \dot{x_2}]^T$$

However I seem to be "ignoring" the constant terms in the equations? Am I ok to do this?

Comment: First of all, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a better math writting. The second row of the matrix $A$ is wrong and you cannot ignore the nonhomogeneous term.

Comment: Can I treat the constant as in input in state space?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "input in state space", but the nonhomogeneous terms are in general source or perturbation terms.

Comment: If I wish to write this in state space form Ax+Bu, B is a 4 row vector, can I put 20, and 30 in my matrix B? If so, what would B look like? Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you see my answer? I wrote $b$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $x=[x_1,\dot{x_1},x_2,\dot{x_2}]^T$, your equation can be written as
$$
\dot x= Ax+b,
$$
where
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 &0 &0\\
-50 & 0 & -250 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $b=[0,20,0,30]^T$. The homogeneous equation can be easily solved after you have computed the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and it is given by $x_H(t)=e^{tA}x(0)$. As the nonhomogeneous term is constant, you can simply write the general solution as $x(t)=x_H(t)+bt.$

Answer (score 0):

The first order system with constant coefficients $\dot x=Ax+b$ can be simplified and solved using the exponential of $A$ as integrating factor,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-At}x(t))=e^{-At}(\dot x(t)-Ax(t))=e^{-At}b.
$$
To compute the matrix exponential, you need the eigen-decomposition of $A$, without any influence of the inhomogeneous part $b$.

Comment: Can I get this in state space by considering the constant an input?

Comment: If it helps your intuition, then yes, you may interpret $b$ as input or control.

Comment: So there is no need to compute the integrating factor, no? I can just write Ax+Bu and do analysis in the fequency domain? Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, usually for manual computation you determine the left eigenvectors and use linear combinations of the equations accordingly so that the system reduces to a collection of (mostly) independent scalar equations.